# Different types of form data - is there a better way to preview the input data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on school project which is a web page for displaying and creating new school courses. At the moment I'm working on previewing a form with different types of data (multiple sets of radios, checkboxes, textareas etc.). I'm presenting the preview in a [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).

I've done this the manual way for now by basically making variables for everything, but I want to make it more efficient and less inconvenient. I'm unsure of how to approach this because I got different types of data like I mentioned and I'm only interested in presenting the data that the user has set/chosen, each in their own paragraph. If the user haven't selected any checkboxes within a set of checkboxes or if a textarea is empty I want to print a short and specific 'error' message within that paragraph, which I've tried to demonstrate in the code below.

I've looked into and thought of using querySelectorAll(), map and/or arrays, but so far I haven't gotten any way in wrapping my head around this problem of mine.

This is just a rewritten sample of the type of data I've got in the form and how I've 'manually' solved it so far:

```js
function previewForm(){
    const previewTerm = document.getElementById("previewTerm");
    const previewLanguage = document.getElementById("previewLanguage");
    const previewFaculty = document.getElementById("previewFaculty");
    const previewDescription = document.getElementById("previewDescription");

    let getTermChecked = $(':checkbox[name=termCheckbox]:checked');
    let getLanguageChecked = $(':radio[name=languageRadio]:checked');
    let getFacultySelected = $('#responsibleFaculty option:selected');
    let getDescriptionValue = $('#description').val();

    /** Term */
    if (getTermChecked.next('label').text() === "") {
       previewTerm.innerHTML = 'No term chosen.';
    } else {
       previewTerm.innerHTML = getTermChecked.next('label').map((i, e) => e.innerText).toArray().join(" and ");
    }

    if (getLanguageChecked.next('label').text() === "") {
       previewLanguage.innerHTML = 'No language chosen.';
    } else {
         previewLanguage.innerHTML = getLanguageChecked.next('label').text();
    }

    if (getDescriptionValue === '') {
         previewDescription.innerHTML = 'No description given.';
    } else {
       previewDescription.innerHTML = getDescriptionValue;
    }

    /** Faculty */
    if (getFacultySelected.index() === 0) {
         previewFaculty.innerHTML = 'No faculty chosen.';
    } else {
         previewFaculty.innerHTML = getFacultySelected.text();
    }
}
```

HTML

```html
<!-- Semester -->
<div class="row">
  <h5>Term</h5>
    <input id="termSpring" name="termCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="0">
    <label for="termSpring">Spring</label>

    <input id="termFall" name="termCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
    <label for="termFall">Fall</label>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <h5>Language</h5>
     <input id="norwegian" name="languageRadio" type="radio" value="norwegian" required>
     <label for="norwegian">Norwegian</label>

     <input id="english" name="languageRadio" type="radio" value="english">
     <label for="english">English</label>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <h5>Responsible faculty</h5>
   <div>
     <select id="responsibleFaculty" name="responsibleFaculty">
        <option disabled selected hidden>Choose responsible faculty..</option>
        <option value="0">Faculty0</option>
        <option value="1">Faculty1</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <h5>Description</h5>
     <textarea name="description" id="description" maxlength="255" type="text" required></textarea>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <h5></h5>
  <button onclick="previewForm()" type="button" id="preview">Preview final version</button>
</div>

<p id="previewTerm"></p>
<p id="previewLanguage"></p>
<p id="previewFaculty"></p>
<p id="previewDescription"></p>
```

I've made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3by9281/3/) to better demonstrate what I currently have and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to better organize it, move every fetch of data ( for example getting the language) to different self contained functions.

Make sure any data validation is done within those functions.

Make all these functions follow a pattern where if the data is invalid or not present, return null.

Have a final function that will call all the smaller get functions and combine them in a js object and return that data ( all the data that was not null perhaps)

There isn't really a good way of fetching data from inputs and text fields unless you build them with Javascript... That way you may have some common logic for inputs and you may be able to work with those objects rather than the actual html elements.